# Hyperplane Translation confusion $H = \{ v \in V \mid \alpha \cdot v = 0\}$ and $J = \{v \in V \mid \alpha \cdot v = k\}$

Tags: calculus

I recently asked a question in another post that was related to this.

I have a vector space $V \cong \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and a hyperplane $H =  \{ v \in V \mid \alpha \cdot v = 0\}$. I also the supposed translated hyperplane of $H$, $J = \{ v \in V \mid \alpha \cdot v = k\}$ where $k$ is some constant.

I do not understand why $J$ is a translation of $H$. Could anyone explain to me using the definition of the dot product why $J$ is indeed a translation?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We fix some vector $v_0 \in J$.
Then $\alpha \cdot v_0 = k$.
For every other $v \in V$ we have that
\begin{align*}
        v \in J
  &\iff \alpha \cdot v = k \\
  &\iff \alpha \cdot v = \alpha \cdot v_0 \\
  &\iff \alpha \cdot v - \alpha \cdot v_0 = 0 \\
  &\iff \alpha \cdot (v - v_0) = 0 \\
  &\iff v - v_0\in H \\
  &\iff v \in H + v_0.
\end{align*}
Thus we have that $J = H + v_0$ is a translated version of $H$.

Comment: Jendrik, so $J = H+v_0$ such that $\alpha \cdot v_0 = k$. So $H$ is translated by whatever $v_0$ is, but does the $k$ tell us something about how much it is translated by? I think we can have very many different $v$'s such that $\alpha \cdot v = k$ is true. So how do we know how much to translate the plane by?